# How to conditionally change state in useEffect after a delay in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a loading message after 1.5 seconds of waiting, if the thing is still loading:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (loading) setSleepMessage("The server seems to be sleeping. Waking it up, wait a second...");
  }, 1500);
}, [loading]);
```

The variable `loading` is a boolean in state returned by an Apollo hook, and `setSleepMessage` is hooked to state too:

```js
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// ...
  const [ sleepMessage, setSleepMessage ] = useState<string>();
  const { data , loading } = useQuery(SOME_QUERY);
  // ...
```

For some reason my logic fails here; the sleep message is rendered after 1.5 seconds no matter whether `loading` has changed from `true` to `false` at that point. Why is this? Is its value in `setTimeout` evaluated right away even though the function is to be executed after the timer expires? Or am I missing something else here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clean up your effects by returning a function to clear the timeout. I suggest also only initiating the timeout if `loading` is true.

```
useEffect(() => {
  let timerId;

  if (loading) {
    timerId = setTimeout(() => {
      setSleepMessage(
        "The server seems to be sleeping. Waking it up, wait a second..."
      );
    }, 1500);
  }
  return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
}, [loading]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't clear the previous timeout.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
    if (loading) setSleepMessage("The server seems to be sleeping. Waking it up, wait a second...");
  }, 1500);

  return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}, [loading]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the query is loading so the value of `loading` is true, the setTimeout will be put into JS call stack and keep the value of `loading` is true, after 1,5s it is put into task queue. After some ticks, the call stack is empty, it will put the callback function inside setTimeout back to callstack and `setSleepMessage` is executed. So that why the sleep message is rendered after 1.5 seconds no matter whether loading is true or false. You should `clearTimeout` in `useEffect` to prevent this happens.

You can read more about `event loop` in JS to dive deeper.